# Spring form select not displaying the value as the selected value

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am using a form select , however the value for the drop down is not showing up as selected.I have the following Model

```
 public class Customer{
 public ConditionalBean conditional
}
```

The ConditionalBean is as follows:

```
public class ConditionalBean {
 private String conditionalName;
 private String conditionalType;
}
```

In the jsp I have the following

```
<form:select path=customer.conditional.conditionalName>
  <form:options items="${optionsMap}"/>
 </form:select>
```

When I display the conditional name

```
   <td>${customer.conditional.conditionalName}</td>
```

it is correctly showing up

However on the drop down the value of the select is not being shown as selected.
I have been able to successfully do it for other dropdowns ,where the path references a regular String.
Here, it is the ConditionalBean object's conditonalName.

Any idea how to fix this? I looked into using  using a PropertyEditorSupport but not sure how to use it.

The options for the select were created as follows:

```
   Map<String,String>optionsMap = new HashMap<String,String>
   optionsMap.put(conditionalName,conditionalName);
```

Comment: There is no difference when path references to String and when path references to String of nested object. Select should work same way. Can you check, that `conditional.conditionalName` contains any value, and not null or empty string?

Comment: what is optionsMap type ? List<String> ?

Comment: The options are of type Map<String,String>. Although the correct selected value is being written to the database. When the screen comes up instead of displaying the selected value, it is showing the first value of the options from the options list.

Comment: Did u check that customer.conditional.conditionalName is one of the key in your optionsMap?
If there is a key matching to customer.conditional.conditionalName then a corresponding value would be selected.

Comment: thanks for the response . I edited the question. Essentially for the optionsMap, the key and value are the same thing- which is the conditionalName, which is a string like "CONDITIONAL VALUE" or "UNCONDITIONAL VALUE" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks kuldeep S Chauhan for the tip. I checked the values in the Map that was populating the options and identified that the key had a trailing space. After trimming the space, it is correctly being displayed.
Thanks!